# What is the language of choice for shell scripting under a generic Windows installation?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting

What is the equivalent of the POSIX compliant `sh` shell language or `bash` extensions in the Windows world ?

What is the optimal choice when writing a script that is supposed to run on as many different versions of Windows as possible ?

I need a solution that is supposed to be already present/installed on the client side, so I tend to exclude the only scripting solution that I know of, [`Powershell`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), and I'm considering Windows XP as the oldest target.

Comment: Powershell. Powershell. Powershell. There are the mingw and Cygwin projects, but on Windows .. Powershell. And scrap any OS that can't utilize it ;-) Anyway, there is *also* [WSH+JScript/VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) for scripting (not a shell environment), but I recommend not going so legacy.

Comment: @user2864740 apparently it is only installed by default with Windows 7 and later ( AFAIK )

Comment: The only thing that is "installed by default" in Windows is cmd.exe (worst. shell. ever.) and some mediocre command-line programs: Powershell.

Comment: Excluding PowerShell just because it might not be on pre-SP2 XP seems silly, considering XP itself is being EOL'ed next month. If you really want to be silly, good old fashioned batch files are your only option; nothing else will be available on every windows machine. An XP machine without SP2/3 is almost certainly unusable for your end users anyway, since it's too busy participating in a botnet to run your script.

Comment: @Wooble the thing is that XP is still very widely adopted, but since I would like to get the entire picture, I'm asking what are the options if I'll decide to drop XP and what are the solutions starting from what version of Windows ( always talking about pre-installed and already available solutions ) . Please specify the name of scripting language and not just the framework .

Answer (score 2):

I know you do not want to read this: If you need a solution to be present on the client side from XP to 8.1 try to do your scripts with Windows cmd.exe.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is the name of the utility, but what is the name of the scripting language ?

Comment: Standard Windows Shell [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx)

Comment: SO resource [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170/best-windows-command-line-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: 3 people keep suggesting Powershell, I already know of it, the problem is that it's not really the best choice in my case.

Comment: +1. Windows CMD (http://ss64.com/nt/) is probably the best universal option in Windows world for simple scripts. I would give an honorable mention to AutoIT (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), which can produce a compiled, native executable (no runtime required). This is more akin to VBScript, but arguably easier to use since it has it's own IDE. AutoIT will run on XP or later Windows OSes and is vastly superior to CMD (or VBScript) for automation or anything requiring any kind of UI.